# Android Camera не выводит в image view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Мое приложение должно фотографировать и выводить на экран.
Сделал все как в примере [здесь](https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/254-urok-131-kamera-ispolzuem-sistemnoe-prilozhenie.html).
В итоге у меня создается папка, в нее заносится фотография, но не выводится на экран.

Пробовал получать URI моей фотографии и через URI вставлять в `ImageView` - все равно не работает.

Ставил логи, по логам понял что ошибка где-то в `onActionResult`.

```
public class User extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

File directory;

final int TYPE_PHOTO = 1;

final int REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO = 1;

Uri imgAddress;

ImageView ivPhoto;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);
    createDirectory();
    ivPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onCreate???");
}

private void createDirectory() {
    directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "Meassure Preassure Pic");
    if (!directory.exists())
        directory.mkdirs();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "DIRECTORY");
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (intent == null) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Intent is null");
            } else {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Photo uri: " + intent.getData());
                Bundle bndl = intent.getExtras();
                if (bndl != null) {
                    Object obj = intent.getExtras().get("data");
                    if (obj instanceof Bitmap) {
                        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) obj;
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "bitmap " + bitmap.getWidth() + " x " + bitmap.getHeight());
                        ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Canceled");
        }
    }
}

private Uri generatefileURI(int type) {
    File file = null;
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_PHOTO:
            file = new File(directory.getPath() + "/" + "photo_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");
            break;
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "fileName= " + file);
    imgAddress = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "moi pyt' " + imgAddress.toString());
    return Uri.fromFile(file);
}

public void onClickPhoto(View view) {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "ONCLICKSTART");
    Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, generatefileURI(TYPE_PHOTO));
    startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE_PHOTO);

    ivPhoto.setImageURI(imgAddress);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
  }
}
```

Comment: ох ох ох.. не используйте логи для отладки это же пипец как неудобно. используйте дебаггер, расставьте где нужно точки останова и проверяйте где и что вызывается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой подход старый и уже не работает. Нельзя передавать `Bitmap` в `intent`. У `intent` есть ограничения по размеру. Сейчас надо делать фото и передавать путь к этой фотографии. В `onActivityResult` доставать из `intent` этот путь и по нему загружать фото в `ImageView`
Посмотрите на этот [пример](https://android.jlelse.eu/androids-new-image-capture-from-a-camera-using-file-provider-dd178519a954).